# Select Distinct entries of a table based on column

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

My model for a blog:

```
class BlogEntry(tzsearch.SearchableModel):
    """Models an blog entry."""
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    category = db.StringProperty(default="Uncategorised", indexed=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now I want to display the categories on a web page. So here is what I did in my views:

```
class CategoriesMainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        categories = db.GqlQuery("SELECT distinct category FROM BlogEntry")
        print categories.count()
        template_values = {
            'categories':categories,
        }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('categories_index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

I am getting error when I iterate over 'categories' in my template. Here is the error that I'm getting:

```
BadValueError: Property title is required
```

My template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 separate-post-item">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <a href="/category/{{ category.category }}">{{ category.category }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I am unable to think of any other way to do this. Any help?

Comment: What does the template do with 'categories'? (Include that bit of code.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the items in the `categories` list is missing the `title` property, which is flagged with `required=True` in the model. Either the item is not really a BlogEntry or it is somehow corrupted (maybe created *before* the model was modified to include the `title` property or its `required` flag set - otherwise it would have caused an exception at object creation time).